# Schengen area residence permit

Tags: schengen, international-travel, residency, hungary

I have a residence permit from Hungary. Can I travel to France if my permit expires in ten days? I'm planning to come back from travel and leave before it expires.

Comment: What kind of resident permit?  Refugee document?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik valid residence in any of schengen countries lets you travel within schengen zone without any doubts & problems.